# How do I get two finger scrolling working on an Acer S3 Elantech Touchpad?

Tags: 11.10, touchpad, multi-touch, elantech

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 on the Acer S3 ultrabook and I am trying to get the touchpad to work with two button scrolling. When I go to System Settings -> Mouse and Touchpad I don't see any touchpad preferences there, only basic mouse settings.

When I run xinput I get the following:

```
 Virtual core pointer                           id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
    Virtual core XTEST pointer                  id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
    PS/2 Elantech Touchpad                      id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

Does anyone know how to get the touchpad working ?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem ? It is a bug, see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/681904/comments/59 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/512192 and http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=9271851

Answer (score 4):

First off does the touch-pad support two finger scrolling? If so the result of `synclient -l` would be nice to edit

add the output of the command synclient -l.

```
Parameter settings:
    LeftEdge                = 1775
    RightEdge               = 5503
    TopEdge                 = 1652
    BottomEdge              = 4662
    FingerLow               = 24
    FingerHigh              = 29
    FingerPress             = 255
    MaxTapTime              = 180
    MaxTapMove              = 245
    MaxDoubleTapTime        = 180
    SingleTapTimeout        = 180
    ClickTime               = 100
    FastTaps                = 0
    EmulateMidButtonTime    = 75
    EmulateTwoFingerMinZ    = 10
    EmulateTwoFingerMinW    = 6
    VertScrollDelta         = 111
    HorizScrollDelta        = 111
    VertEdgeScroll          = 0
    HorizEdgeScroll         = 0
    CornerCoasting          = 0
    VertTwoFingerScroll     = 1
    HorizTwoFingerScroll    = 0
    MinSpeed                = 1
    MaxSpeed                = 1.75
    AccelFactor             = 0.0359131
    TrackstickSpeed         = 40
    EdgeMotionMinZ          = 29
    EdgeMotionMaxZ          = 159
    EdgeMotionMinSpeed      = 1
    EdgeMotionMaxSpeed      = 445
    EdgeMotionUseAlways     = 0
    TouchpadOff             = 0
    LockedDrags             = 0
    LockedDragTimeout       = 5000
    RTCornerButton          = 2
    RBCornerButton          = 3
    LTCornerButton          = 0
    LBCornerButton          = 0
    TapButton1              = 1
    TapButton2              = 3
    TapButton3              = 2
    ClickFinger1            = 1
    ClickFinger2            = 1
    ClickFinger3            = 1
    CircularScrolling       = 0
    CircScrollDelta         = 0.1
    CircScrollTrigger       = 0
    CircularPad             = 0
    PalmDetect              = 0
    PalmMinWidth            = 9
    PalmMinZ                = 199
    CoastingSpeed           = 20
    CoastingFriction        = 50
    PressureMotionMinZ      = 29
    PressureMotionMaxZ      = 159
    PressureMotionMinFactor = 1
    PressureMotionMaxFactor = 1
    ResolutionDetect        = 1
    GrabEventDevice         = 1
    TapAndDragGesture       = 1
    AreaLeftEdge            = 0
    AreaRightEdge           = 0
    AreaTopEdge             = 0
    AreaBottomEdge          = 0
```

You can change the setting of the synclient by adding to the startup application a new application with the following command:

```
xterm -e synclient "EmulateTwoFingerMinZ=10"
```

This would change the setting of EmulateTwoFingerMinZ to the value of 10

Found similar answer here: [How to get two-finger scolling to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75359/how-to-get-two-finger-scolling-to-work)

Comment: I think the OP is long gone and I appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 0):

1)Click the top-right icon of your desktop and select "System Settings"

2)Click the "Mouse and Trackpad" icon

3)Go to "Touchpad" tab, check the "Two-finger scrolling" option and check "Enable horizontal scrolling"

Now you must have two finger scrolling.. :)

Comment: The OP indicated "When I go to System Settings -> Mouse and Touchpad I don't see any touchpad preferences there, only basic mouse settings".

Answer (score 0):

Install ubuntu tweak (latest version from repository). Then click on Tweaks->miscellaneous->natural scrolling