# How to get two-finger scolling to work?

Tags: 11.10, touchpad

Always wanted this feature but it never works in ubuntu. Is there any hack/mod to get it to work? My laptop is an Acer 5532, and my touchpad is from Synaptics. The latest drivers from Synaptics made two-finger scolling possible with Windos 7, so I'm guessing there's some way to work in Ubuntu/Linux.

Comment: What is the model of your touchpad? Or, at least, the model of your laptop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I guess you enabled the two finger scrolling as described in my first answer. As you cannot post the results of synclient -l try the following:

Open start up applications and add a new application and write the following command into the command line

xterm -e synclient "EmulateTwoFingerMinZ=10"

this will change the most probably too high value in synclient.

Comment: welcome, I also like two finger scrolling. Look also for easystroke to widen the capabilities of your touchpad. I use it especially for navigating inside the browser, close apps and send my computer to sleep.

Comment: I tried it and found it to be very useful. THanks a lot. You've really helped me and probably many other users.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to change the settings of the mouse in the control center?

[image: mouse settings]

If it still does not work, run `synclient -l` in the terminal and provide us the results.

Comment: How do I post the info here. Text box won't allow me to post all the info.

Comment: Link to a pastebin URL.

Answer (score 0):

Touchpads explicitely need to support multi finger gestures. If you do not have such a touchpad, you are out of luck.

That's all to say without more information about your touchpad.